# Simulate control delay

Tags: drake

I'm working on different optimal controllers and test them with drake solver and simulator. For this I implement the controllers as a `LeafSystem`, where the actual control step is triggered by using a `PeriodicDiscreteUpdateEvent`:

```
self.DeclarePeriodicDiscreteUpdateEvent(period_sec=0.1, offset_sec=0.0, update=self._discrete_update)
```

```
def _discrete_update(self, context : Context, discrete_state : DiscreteValues):
    system_state = self._plant_output_port.Eval(context)
    control_input, time = self._control(system_state)
    discrete_state.get_mutable_vector(0).SetFromVector(control_input)
```

The controller output is then defined as folllowing:

```
self._plant_input_port = self.DeclareStateOutputPort(name="plant_input", state_index=self._out_state)
```

This works quite well, however as I want to test the feedback system as close to reality as possible I am not quite sure how to model the actual control delay. As it is an optimal controller, the method call to `self._control(system_state)` can take up to 0.1s.

If I understand the drake simulation correctly, when the UpdateEvent is triggered, the whole simulation waits for the controller to calculate the input, updates the discrete states (control input) and then integrates the continuous system based on the new control input.
However, what I want is that the system "moves forward" while the controller is calculating the input, like in reality.

I tried the `_discrete_update` method to write the control input to another intermediate discrete state vector and added another `PeriodicDiscreteUpdateEvent`, which has a time offset of 0.1s and takes the intermediate state to the actual output state. However, I'm not sure if this creates some race conditions. Also, I found the `DiscreteTimeDelay` block that I might use. However, all this approaches dont use the actual solving time but just postpone the output by a fixed value.
I was wondering if there is a proper way of enforcing my desired behavior.

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/11093, and perhaps comment there. It has some discussion on this topic.  Introducing a fixed delay is definitely much easier (conceptually and in the code) if you think it might be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast replay. Indeed, i somehow oversaw this issue.